# Create enum using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, enums, runtime

Does `C#` offer a way to create `Enum` type **from scratch** using reflection?

Suppose, I have a collection of `strings`: `{"Single", "Married", "Divorced"}` and I'm willing to build the following enum type *in runtime:*

```
enum PersonStatus
{
    Single, Married, Divorced
}
```

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: `enum`is a contract, what is the meaning of creating it in _runtime_?

Comment: @gdoron enums can be interpretted and used at runtime, so it's certainly not impossible for there to be value in emitting them a runtime, though Chris' answer hits on what's really useful in this case.

Comment: @JonHanna. Please show me one scenario where it's needed, because in this scenario it's NOT!

Comment: @gdoron Why should I? I've said it can be done, and I've said it's not needed here.

Comment: An enum is used if you have an object that has only a limited number of values, especially if the number of values is fairly small. The nice thing about using an enum is that at compile time it is already checked that you don't assign an invalid value to an object of the enum type. Suppose you have some hardware that has a parameter with a limited number of values that you can only detect at runtime. Using enumbuilder you can check at compile time that no invalid value will be assigned at runtime, because you can only assign values you got from the enumtype as allowed values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not without doing really gnarly things like generating assemblies using Emit.  How would you use such an enum anyway?  Whats the real goal here?

EDIT: Now that we know what you really want to do, [this page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/objectlistview/forums/forum/812922/topic/3403242) suggests that you can acheive your goal using code like the following:

```
private void listViewComplex_CellEditStarting(object sender, CellEditEventArgs e)
{
    // Ignore edit events for other columns
    if (e.Column != this.columnThatYouWantToEdit)
        return;

    ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
    cb.Bounds = e.CellBounds;
    cb.Font = ((ObjectListView)sender).Font;
    cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    cb.Items.AddRange(new String[] { "Single", "Married", "Divorced" });
    cb.SelectedIndex = 0; // should select the entry that reflects the current value
    e.Control = cb;
}
```

Comment: @Well, I'm using `ObjectListView` control, which can automatically display useful editing hints when the value is a `enum`. I thought that if there is a simple way to generate them programmatically, it would be a nice solution.

Comment: Thank you, I've already implemented something similiar (dropping combobox) myself. Also the `Reflection.Emit` seems to be a nice feature to know about.

Answer (score 9):

> Does C# offer a way to create Enum type from scratch using reflection?

Yes, it's possible. If you want to create types (including enums) at runtime you could use [Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx) in order to *emit* the actual MSIL code.

Here's a [concrete example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.modulebuilder.defineenum.aspx) of how to achieve that using the `DefineEnum` method.

Comment: What's Reflection.Emit if not standaard reflection?

Comment: Not that it's what the OP actually needed, but there's always the next person coming in on a google search :)

Comment: `Emit` is about code injection, `reflection` is about available data *manipulation* too. They **are** different.

Comment: @JonHanna, what makes you think that this is not the code that the OP needed? What makes you think that the only way to respond to the sentence `Suppose, I have a collection of strings: {"Single", "Married", "Divorced"} and I'm willing to build the following enum type in runtime:` is to use reflection emit and provide a specific example of how to do that? Of course feel free to downvote my answer if you think that it is wrong and in addition to that you might provide your answer that you think would be correct. Sorry to having to say this but your behavior really pisses me off.

Comment: Really? I'm up-voting your answer because I thought it was a very good one. I didn't answer myself, because your answer said what I was going to say, except I disagreed on one point. I think Chris' edit is a better answer to what the OP added in his comment on Chris' answer, but I think it's great that someone googling about creating enums through reflection might find your answer which is more likely to be what *they* want than Chris' as yours best answers the question with more limited information originally given.

Comment: @JonHanna, sorry if I misunderstood your comment. My English is very bad. I completely agreed with your first comment when you said that Reflection.Emit is actually Reflection and that's why I updated my answer. Sorry once again for my confusion. I feel I completely misunderstood your comment about Google. Language barrier :-)

Comment: Well, there's my being more concise than I might otherwise because of the character limit may have made me sound more terse than I intended.