# can Enum contains other Enum?

Tags: c#, silverlight, enums, ienumerable

Can Enum contains other Enum elements along with its own elements ?

```
public enum CardSuit
{
    spades,
    hearts,
    diamonds,
    clubs 
}

public enum GameSuit
{
    spades,        //        These are 
    hearts,        //        the same
    diamonds,      //      " CardSuit "
    clubs,         //        elements

    suns    //             " GameSuit " special element
}
```

Can we include CardSuit in GameSuit without redundant retyping same elements ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly no, there's no good solution for what you want using enums.  There are other options you can try, such as a series of `public static readonly` fields of a particular "enum-like" type:

```
public class CardSuit 
{
    public static readonly CardSuit Spades = new CardSuit();
    public static readonly CardSuit Hearts = new CardSuit();
    ...
}

public enum GameSuit : CardSuit 
{
    public static readonly GameSuit Suns = new GameSuit();
}
```

In practice, this can work mostly as well, albeit without `switch` statement support.  Usage might be like:

```
var cardSuit = ...;
if (cardSuit == CardSuit.Spades || cardSuit == GameSuit.Suns) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have typed is legal but both enums are independent of each other.

`GameSuit` enum spades has no connection with `CardsSuit` enum spades.

Comment: +1 GameSuit enum spades has no connection with CardsSuit enum spades.

Answer (score 2):

You can carry values from one enumerated type to another explicitly:

```
public enum Foo { a, b, c }
public enum Bar { a = Foo.a, b = Foo.b, c = Foo.c + 3, d }
```

Comment: That won't work in practice.  When `Foo foo = Bar.d` doesn't compile, what is the point?  (not to mention that `Foo.c + 3` is rather hideous)

Comment: @KirkWoll - I wouldn't expect `Bar.d` to be assignable to an instance of `Foo`.

Comment: Right, I know.  So...if you can't exchange the "extending" enum with the original, what is the point?  You're left with two enums that are similar but bear no syntactic relationship with one another.

Comment: @KirkWoll - Begging your pardon.  When the OP asked "Can we include CardSuit in GameSuit without redundant retyping same elements" I thought they wanted to create a new type.  Unfortunately the following code does not throw an exception: `public enum Foo { a, b, c }  public enum Bar { a = Foo.a, b = Foo.b, c = Foo.c, d } Foo foo = Foo.b; Bar bar = (Bar)(int)foo; bar = Bar.d; foo = (Foo)(int)bar;`

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to give up switch support. You can account for various other enum types by setting the starting integer value.

```
const int baseOfCardSuit = 0;
const int baseOfGameSuit = 4;

public enum CardSuit
{
    spades = baseOfCardSuit,
    hearts, // 1
    diamonds, // 2
    clubs // 3
};

public enum GameSuit
{
    suns = baseOfGameSuit
};
```

Casting to invalid enum values does not modify the integer value.

```
GameSuit a = (GameSuit) CardSuit.spades;
Console.WriteLine(a); // "0"
CardSuit b = (CardSuit) GameSuit.suns;
Console.WriteLine(b); // "4"
```

And so enum types are interchangeable.

```
int value = 4; // "GameSuit.*"
switch((CardSuit)value) 
{
  case CardSuit.spades:
  case CardSuit.hearts:
  case CardSuit.diamonds:
  case CardSuit.clubs:
     Console.WriteLine("CardSuit.*");
     break;
  default: 
     switch((GameSuit)value) 
     {
         case GameSuit.sums:
            Console.WriteLine("GameSuit.*");
            break;
         default:
            Console.WriteLine("Err: value not found");
            break;  
     }
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enum is a special class, with special behavior. You can't directly inherit this class, but it's inderectly inheriter any time you declare a new `enum`.

You cannot inherit one new `enum` from other `enum`.

The only way you can do something like that, would be using reflection. But you don't get  what you want to do. This can so how far you can get using Refletcion with enums:

- [Create enum using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979179/create-enum-using-reflection)
- [Setting Enum's Through Reflection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15292/Setting-Enum-s-Through-Reflection)

But I'm afraid this doesn't server your purpose.